# What hook for installing a large list of field options?

Tags: 7, hooks, entities

If a custom module installs a dropdown-style field, using a large internal list of options (about 200 items), should this list be populated in `hook_install` or `hook_init` for greatest efficiency?
Yes, I know, with such an extensive list, I should provide an ajax-driven widget for ease of use, but at this stage of development and my skills this is a side issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use the [List field predefined options](http://drupal.org/project/list_predefined_options) module.